# Análisis de sentimiento en Español con StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, java-ee, twitter-api, inteligencia-artificial, nlp

Quiero determinar la polaridad de tweets recibidos mediante la librería Twitter4j. Para ello he visto que StanfordCoreNLP es una buena alternativa, para análisis de sentimiento en Inglés funciona bien pero para texto en Español, no entiendo muy bien como configurarlo o hacerlo. ¿Alguién tiene esperiencia en este campo y me puede ayudar?

Comment: yo tengo un problema parecido. No encuentro ningún paquete que sea con palabras en español. ¿Sabéis si tidytext se puede configurar a español? Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues es muy sencillo. ¿Ya tes has descargado el .zip y el .jar correspondiente a castellano de http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#download ?

Luego:

```
$ unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09.zip
...
$ cd stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09
$ cp ../stanford-spanish-corenlp-2015-10-14-models.jar .
$ cat > entrada.txt
Madrid es la capital de España. Es muy antigua, tiene como 1000 años.
^D
$ java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties  -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos  -file entrada.txt -outputFormat conll
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/spanish/spanish-distsim.tagger ... done [4.6 sec].

Processing file ...../entrada.txt ... writing to  ..../entrada.txt.conll
Annotating file ..../entrada.txt
done.
Annotation pipeline timing information:
TokenizerAnnotator: 2.3 sec.
WordsToSentencesAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
POSTaggerAnnotator: 0.1 sec.
TOTAL: 2.3 sec. for 16 tokens at 6.8 tokens/sec.
Pipeline setup: 4.9 sec.
Total time for StanfordCoreNLP pipeline: 7.4 sec.
$ cat entrada.txt.conll
1   Madrid  _   np00000 _   _   _
2   es      _   vsip000 _   _   _
3   la      _   da0000  _   _   _
4   capital _   nc0s000 _   _   _
5   de      _   sp000   _   _   _
6   España  _   np00000 _   _   _
7   .       _   fp      _   _   _

1   Es      _   vsip000 _   _   _
2   muy     _   rg      _   _   _
3   antigua _   aq0000  _   _   _
4   ,       _   fc      _   _   _
5   tiene   _   vmip000 _   _   _
6   como    _   cs      _   _   _
7   1000    _   z0      _   _   _
8   años    _   nc0p000 _   _   _
9   .       _   fp      _   _   _

$
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, lo preguntaba porque he visto en esta página http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html que el Análisis de sentimiento para el Español no está soportado. De todas formas lo pruebo y te comento :)

Comment: Haber empezado por ahi. ;-)